# Jquery ajax responsed content does not write into the html form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

HTML code :

I echo this content in php file, In result i get only the 'Contact Us' Remaining part does not display the html form

```
<div > Contact Us 
  <form name="profile" action="" method="post"> 
    Name : <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" />
    Email : <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
    Mobile : <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Jquery code response :

```
$.post("contact_us.php",{ user_id:$('#user_id').val(),typ:'contact_us' },
 function(data) {   
   $('#contact_us').html(data); 
});
```

In contact_us id does not write the contact us form, Please anyone help me

Comment: this could be a lot of things, using firebug, can you post us the exact error you are getting?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using Firebug?

http://getfirebug.com/

That will let you see what the script is returning.

UPDATE:

You are referencing a container with ID = "contact_us"

```
$('#contact_us').html(data);
```

You need to set the ID of the div you want to replace the content in.

```
<div id="contact_us"></div>
```

Comment: Yes i tried , In firebug Net tab Post Response showing full data, but in HTML showing only the 'Contact Us' , it does not show inside form tag content

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML isn't valid. You need to close the div tag

```
<div >
  Contact Us 
  <form name="profile" action="" method="post"> 
    Name : <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" />
  </form>
</div>
```